# How to re reference modified dll

Tags: asp.net

in my asp.net solution i have created two projects. One is Class Library. First, I have referenced Class Library dll to other project. Now I have added new class into Class Library but cannot see it in the other project. I have removed that reference and added as a new reference but still have the problem. 
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you have added the new class in a different namespace?
e.g.

```
namespace Company.Stuff
{
   class Controller
   {
      //...
   }
}
```

In which case after adding your project reference you would need to import the namespace. E.g.

```
using Company.Stuff;

class AnotherClass
{
   var controller = new Controller();
   //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is by doing a [project reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez524kew%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). In this case you will not need to rebuild or re-reference the DLL each time, and the other project will be built as well each time.

Note that this is assuming they are in the same solution.